# Best design pattern/approach for a Factory which needs multiple types of input

Tags: design, design-patterns, software, factory, abstract-factory

I want to develop a Factory of INotifications.

```
public interface INotification
{
    string Text { get; }
    string UserId { get; }
    NotificationType NotificationType { get; }
}
```

The problem is, that the NotificationFactory has to be ready for getting multiple types of inputs , why? because there are multiple implementations of INotification, and the factory should be able to return instance of each of them  depending the request.

```
INotification not1= NotificationFactory.GetNotification<EmailNotification>(new Email("hi there"));
INotification not1= NotificationFactory.GetNotification<PackageNotification>(new Package("10$","book"));
INotification not2= NotificationFactory.GetNotification<XXXTypeNotification>(new XXXX);
```

As you see, it would have different types in the input parameters.(they are know at design time) I would not like to create a method for each type of notification the factory is enabled to create...
Ho can i design that Factory? It does not need to use generics , the code I attached is just for understanding the problem.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Variadic variants (params) ? Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params Note that, when this route is taken, the code editor auto-complete doesn't work anymore. This may make it harder to use overall, as users have to remember each argument needed by each function (type of notification). A different approach would be to create wrappers for each type (i.e. your existing classes `Email`, `Package`), and then implement a GetNotification method that accepts an instance of any of these classes, and convert them into a notification object.

Comment: Another approach is to write extension methods - attach them (i.e. make subject) to the the `Email` and `Package` class; name the method `GetNotification`, and take an extra input parameter of type `NotificationFactory`. This requires flipping the subject-object.

Comment: It is probably necessary to write multiple methods anyway, because at the minimum, the compiler needs to know that the method (overloaded, i.e. one or more implementations) return type T1B when given type T1A; return type T2B when given type T2A; and so on. The C# type system doesn't do that.

Comment: Extension methods can improve their specificity (i.e. making them less easily triggered for the wrong inputs) by having their subjects implement interfaces (tag interfaces) exclusively for this purpose (of improving the specificity of extension methods)

Comment: The params approach is not good enough because as you say , it is hard to don't have runtime errors..

Comment: Extension methods i think will make my code less structured and more hard to maintain, i prefer a more losely coupled code that allows me to re-use notification module in other systems

Comment: I think the core of the question, *"I would not like to create a method for each type of notification the factory is enabled to create"*, is just not possible. In other words, for each type there needs to be a method. The method itself need not be generic. (In that case, these methods are "overloaded" - they have the same name but are differentiated by the argument types, so they are unrelated methods.) And to add support for new types of notification inputs, it is necessary to add corresponding methods to the notification factory.

Comment: More context is needed. So far it looks like you want to use Factory antipattern just for the sake of it.

Comment: If all of the input types contain a serialization method to a common data type, something like e.g. `ToJson()` or `ToBlob()`, then the notification can simply wrap this `Json` or `Blob`, therefore the notification factory method can be unified.

Comment: @Basilevs you are wrong, i want to use the design pattern that allows me to generate notifications in a less coupled way, and flexible enough to be easy to add new types. If you know how, tell me

Comment: Speaking of design pattern, this question is an example where the open-closed principle (OCP) is impossible to satisfy (in the presence of a factory class). In C#, with or without generics, the handling of a new type needs new code - unless the new type can be converted (either as data (field extraction or object serialization or conversion) or as inheritance) into an existing type, and reuse the handler for the latter. Adding new code to a class breaks OCP. C# provides partial class and extension methods to workaround OCP. C# can also generate code on the fly (reflection emit, expression ...

Comment: ... expression builder). Design patterns promise to solve these problems, but they typically create a larger monster than they try to solve. (To have a fair discussion, use a practical example with realistic project complexity.) Therefore, given all the considerations, one should just add methods when new types need to be supported.

Comment: What about using the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)? Instead of trying to build one factory "to rule them all", use different factory subclasses for each type of notification.

Comment: @DocBrown could you write some pseudocode?

Comment: For pseudocode I had to write an answer, but this currently makes no sense, because your question contains no hint what actual problem your factory tries to solve. Without such context, it is not clear **what layers or components** you want to decouple in your application, where the generic calling part of the factories live and where the non-generic initialization can be placed. And without that knowledge, it is not clear if an abstract factory can help (and please don't give me the same reply as you gave to Basilevs, that more a non-answer).